# How bad it is to lock a mutex in an infinite loop or an update function

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, mutex

```
std::queue<double> some_q;
std::mutex mu_q;

/* an update function may be an event observer */
void UpdateFunc()
{
    /* some other processing */
    std::lock_guard lock{ mu_q };
    while (!some_q.empty())
    {
        const auto& val = some_q.front();
        /* update different states according to val */
        some_q.pop();
    }
    /* some other processing */
}

/* some other thread might add some values after processing some other inputs */
void AddVal(...)
{
    std::lock_guard lock{ mu_q };
    some_q.push(...);
}
```

For this case is it okay to handle the queue this way?
Or would it be better if I try to use a lock-free queue like the boost one?

Comment: What infinite loop? What does "bad" mean?

Comment: The rule of thumb is that code should hold a mutex for the shortest time necessary for proper synchronization. Whether the use in the question is appropriate depends entirely on the content of `/* update different states according to val */`.

Comment: You use a mutex to safely share a resource, but if you need to hold a resource essentially forever, you aren't really sharing it, are you?

Comment: @PeteBecker so I've some timeout variables which are needed to be updated every frame and some other thread might wanna update those timeouts, so this `UpdateFunc` method will be doing is updating the timeout variables (reduce/increase or call other functions if the timeout has reached to 0) and check if some other thread has asked for updating the timeout then it will update that accordingly

Comment: Access to the queue needs to be synchronized, but only access to the queue. For the rest of the loop the queue doesn't need any protection. Here's a brutally simple example: 1) Lock the mutex. 2) get a copy of the next item in the queue. 3) Remove the item from the queue. 4) Unlock the mutex. 5) process the item removed from the queue. Combine this with a [`condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to signal when a value is in the queue and you can get rid of the busy wait loop. That loop is fatal. The consumer will never be able to add an item.

Comment: @user4581301 so separating those queue parts from the `UpdateFunc` method and putting those in a separate method? sorry, I am not that used to using condition_variables and I also would want the `UpdateFunc` to update the timers if only some thread asked to update those timers but now this totally feels like another topic it's hard for newbies like me to actually express all the problems

Comment: A function is a great idea because it isolates the responsibility of safely getting stuff from the queue. If you have a function that creates a `lock_guard`  and then returns an item from the queue, waits on a `condition_variable` until an item is available if necessary, your life gets much, much easier. Safe threading is not easy. There are a lot of gotchas. The key to writing good code (and good Stack Overflow questions) is to keep the responsibility of any piece of code small. If the problem you need to solve can be made small, it's easier to express and the answers will be better targeted.

Comment: @user4581301 what if i try to use a lock-free queue something which going to pop all the available data when the `UpdateFunc` tries to access if no data is available at that point otherwise just continue with the rest of the execution

Comment: Lock free queue, when you can find one that meets your requirements, is a great tool, but you still have the problem of knowing when to look at the queue. Right now you have a while loop constantly checking whether or not the queue is empty. That's going to result in 100% usage of that CPU core for absolutely no gain almost every time. You will still want a mechanism by which the thread can block and stop using up the CPU until the producer adds a new item to the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How bad it is to lock a mutex in an infinite loop or an update function

It's pretty bad. Infinite loops actually make your program have *undefined behavior* unless it does one of the following:

- terminate
- make a call to a library I/O function
- perform an access through a volatile glvalue
- perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation

Acquiring the mutex lock before entering the loop and just holding it does not count as performing a synchronization operation (in the loop). Also, when holding the mutex, noone can add information to the queue, so while processing the information you extract, all threads wanting to add to the queue will have to wait - and no other worker threads wanting to share the load can extract from the queue either. It's usually better to extract one task from the queue, release the lock and then work with what you got.

The common way is to use a `condition_variable` that lets other threads acquire the lock and then notify other threads waiting with the same `condition_variable`. The CPU will be pretty close to idle while waiting and wake up to do the work when needed.

Using your program as a base, it could look like this:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

std::queue<double> some_q;
std::mutex mu_q;
std::condition_variable cv_q; // the condition variable
bool stop_q = false;          // something to signal the worker thread to quit

/* an update function may be an event observer */
void UpdateFunc() {
    while(true) {
        double val;
        {
            std::unique_lock lock{mu_q};

            // cv_q.wait lets others acquire the lock to work with the queue
            // while it waits to be notified.
            while (not stop_q && some_q.empty()) cv_q.wait(lock);

            if(stop_q) break; // time to quit

            val = std::move(some_q.front());
            some_q.pop();
        } // lock released so others can use the queue

        // do time consuming work with "val" here
        std::cout << "got " << val << '\n';
    }
}

/* some other thread might add some values after processing some other inputs */
void AddVal(double val) {
    std::lock_guard lock{mu_q};
    some_q.push(val);
    cv_q.notify_one(); // notify someone that there's a new value to work with
}

void StopQ() { // a function to set the queue in shutdown mode
    std::lock_guard lock{mu_q};
    stop_q = true;
    cv_q.notify_all(); // notify all that it's time to stop
}

int main() {
    auto th = std::thread(UpdateFunc);
    
    // simulate some events coming with some time apart
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    AddVal(1.2);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    AddVal(3.4);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    AddVal(5.6);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    StopQ();    
    th.join();
}
```

---

If you really want to process everything that is currently in the queue, then extract everything first and then release the lock, then work with what you extracted. Extracting everything from the queue is done quickly by just swapping in another `std::queue`. Example:

```cpp
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> stop_q{}; // needs to be atomic in this version

void UpdateFunc() {
    while(not stop_q) {
        std::queue<double> work; // this will be used to swap with some_q
        {
            std::unique_lock lock{mu_q};

            // cv_q.wait lets others acquire the lock to work with the queue
            // while it waits to be notified.
            while (not stop_q && some_q.empty()) cv_q.wait(lock);

            std::swap(work, some_q); // extract everything from the queue at once
        } // lock released so others can use the queue

        // do time consuming work here
        while(not stop_q && not work.empty()) {
            auto val = std::move(work.front());
            work.pop();

            std::cout << "got " << val << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but I think processing one data at one time would be the right way to do, so I've some timeout variables which are needed to be updated every frame and some other thread might wanna update those timeouts, so this `UpdateFunc` method will be doing is updating the timeout variables (reduce/increase or call other functions if the timeout has reached to 0) and check if some other thread has asked to update the timeout then it will update that accordingly.

Comment: @SanjidHaque Ok, I added an alternative.

Comment: do you think a lock-free queue will perform better for this case than the `condition_variable ` approach?

Comment: @SanjidHaque That's very possible. Implementing it will however not be as simple as what I showed here and the performance provided in my suggestion is good enough for anything but the extreme cases. Be sure that you have an extreme situation before you complicate things.

Comment: ow btw you're solution is missing one of the crucial part of my problem, that `UpdateFunc` supposed to do other works other than just waiting for the queue to have some values

Comment: @SanjidHaque I think you missed a big part of the two different approaches. 1) Do one time consuming thing or 2) Do all av them.

If you have a tweak that needs profiling, fine. I don't see that I missed any basic part though.

Comment: ow yes, I actually misunderstood how the `condition_variable` works, now that's what happens when u lack experience thanks for the later alternative, btw is this how different UI libs handle event polling or some similar design or it's just a bad design only newbies will come up with

Comment: @SanjidHaque I don't know how different UI libraries deals with events internally but, on the surface, what I've seen looks pretty similar to this. Each visual component has its own message queue and use some intrisic waiting mechanism to process messages when they arrive (from what I've understood) - I have very little experience with GUI:s though so perhaps there's more to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like you currently are assuming proper use of the lock across all threads. However, you may run into some frustrations about how you want to call updateFunc().

- Are you going to be using a callback?
- Are you going to be using an ISR?
- Are you going to be polling?

If you use a 3rd party lib it often trivializes thread synchronization and queues

For example, if you are using a [CMSIS RTOS(v2)](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS2/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__Message.html). It is a fairly straight forward process to get multiple threads to pass information between each other. You could have multiple producers, and a single consumer.

The single consumer can wait in a forever loop where it waits to receive a message before performing its work

> when timeout is set to osWaitForever the function will wait for an
> infinite time until the message is retrieved (i.e. wait semantics).

```
// Two producers
osMessageQueuePut(X,Y,Z,timeout=0)
osMessageQueuePut(X,Y,Z,timeout=0)
    
// One consumer which will run only once something enters the queue
osMessageQueueGet(X,Y,Z,osWaitForever)
```

tldr; You are safe to proceed, but using a library will likely make your synchronization problems easier.

Comment: ah, so you're saying my approach is pretty okay? but I was thinking about an issue what if a thread that was calling `AddVal` gets terminated right after locking the mutex wouldn't that make the `UpdateFunc` wait forever coz it would be waiting for the mutex to be unlocked or will the mutex get released if the thread which calls `AddVal` gets terminated

Comment: @SanjidHaque Most (and a lot of the time all) guarantees about program stability go out the window when you terminate a thread. Prefer to allow threads to exit politely.

Comment: @SanjidHaque Look into RAII and why c++ synchronization methods are usually safer. In this case, the lock guard is automatically released when the function goes out of scope. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard. However, if depending on your program, you can still end up in deadlock if multiple threads are all waiting on the mutex and can't finish their sub-routine